# How to execute a method in C# WinForms if a textbox value equals a predermined length

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form where a user enters a 4 digit pin number. When the pin number is entered, I would like to call my method automatically once the last number of the pin number is pressed. I am assuming this needs to be done in a keydown event on the textbox.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
  private void txtPinNumber_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPinNumber.Text.Trim().Length == 4)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                Verify_Pin();
        }
    }
```

It seems to work but the user has to press an addition key to execute the method. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> programmatically and then check for it. Just call the other method.

Also, the `KeyDown` event fires *before* the `Text` property changes to reflect the most recently typed character, so you'll have to place that code in a different event.

Use `TextChanged` or `KeyUp`.

```
private void txtPinNumber_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPinNumber.Text.Trim().Length == 4)
        Verify_Pin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said

`When the pin number is entered, I would like to call my method automatically once the last number of the pin number is pressed.`

So you can simply do this in the `KeyUp` event of your textbox

```
private void txtPinNumber_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPinNumber.Text.Trim().Length == 4)
        Verify_Pin();
}
```

BTW, it is advisable to let user press enter and then you run the code. Because it can be that user accidentally presses the last number wrong.

Comment: `So why can't you simply do` ?? Are you asking for clarification ? because if that is the case then this answer should be a comment.

Comment: @user2711965: Missed that. Updated answer. Thanks.